# How do I do stuff with my form objects from another module?

Tags: vb.net, forms, class, scope

First of all, Why are forms classes?

But now on to the main question.

I have:

`Form1.vb`

`Module1.vb`

On the form there is a textbox, progress bar, labels etc.

I want to be able to change the properties of these objects on my form from module1, but I cant seem to access them.

These things on the form are objects, right? So do they have a certain scope? and how can I change it?

Wait but according to my solution explorer, these things are properties of a class??

[image]

But the form shows up when I run the program?? Wouldn't the form class have to be instantiated so that the form1 object is created?

Not that it matters, but here is a snippet from module1

```
Sub WriteObjectsToCSV()
    Dim props As PropertyInfo() = MyCompanies(1).GetType().GetProperties()
    Dim sw As StreamWriter = 
    My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(SaveAs, False)
    Dim csv As New CsvHelper.CsvWriter(sw)

    csv.WriteHeader(Of Company)()
    csv.NextRecord()

    For Each company In MyCompanies

        '>>> want to write to my text box and change my progress bar here <<<

        For Each prop In props
            csv.WriteField(prop.GetValue(company))
        Next
        csv.NextRecord()
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Forms are classes because it is the 21st Century and it is an Object Oriented world.  Not everything in the picture are objects - some are methods.  Its not clear what  `MyCompanies(1)` is, but you could pass it to the module method.  Depending on what `MyCompanies(1)` is, that code looks to be a homegrown serializer.  You might want to look into the many available serialization methods.

Comment: The Form *is* instantiated - the VB App framework does that for you.  Which form depends on what you set as the `Startup Object` in project properties.  You can also do it from code in a `Sub Main` as `Application.Run(New Form1)`.  If `MyCompanies` is data - rather than pass it to that method, you could also move the method to where the data is (the form).  Existing serializers would drill be worth researching.  In the future try to ask one question per post - this is borderline asking for a tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms are classes because they are created dynamically. You can instantiate and open the same form class serveral times and leave the instances open at the same time.

VB automatically instantiates the main form.

You can access the open forms through `My.Application.OpenForms`. The main form is always the first

```
Dim mainForm As Form1

mainForm = DirectCast(My.Application.OpenForms(0), Form1)
mainForm.txtOutput.Text = "hello"
```

To be able to access the controls of the form from outside, they must be declared `Public` or `Internal`. You can change the access modifier from the properties window (`Modifiers` property).

Instead, you can also declare a property in the form to make the text accessible outside

```
Public Property OutputText() As String
    Get
        Return txtOutput.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        txtOutput.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Now you can write this in the module

```
mainForm.OutputText = "hello"
```